# Get datetime64[ns] between two datetimes pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I'm trying to extract the rows within a certain datetime. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016, 2017, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3, 4, 6],
                   'day': [4, 5, 4, 3]})

df = pd.to_datetime(df)
df = df.to_frame(name='test')

start_date = pd.Timestamp(2016,1,1)
end_date = pd.Timestamp(2017, 5, 1)
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)

print (start_date)
print (end_date)

print (df[df['test'] > start_date & df['test'] < end_date])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There missing `()` becauase priority of operators:

```
print (df[(df['test'] > start_date) & (df['test'] < end_date)])
```

Or use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
print (df[(df['test'].between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=False)])
```

Comment: If we add date and time for example, if the dataframe contains `2017-05-01 00:00:00`. How do you compare then?

Comment: @tandem - Can you add expected output to question?

Comment: I retract, `df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016, 2017, 2016],
                   'month': [2, 3, 4, 6],
                   'day': [4, 5, 4, 3],
                   'hour':[4,4,4,4],
                   'minute':[4,4,4,4],
                   'second':[4,4,4,4],
                   })`
checked and it works for this too. thanks!